# screen flash in phonegap ipad app

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, cordova

i have recently uploaded my first app onto my ipad and when I select a link to another page, the page loads and then the screen flashes white and then goes back to normal. 
I tried to use the css trick;

> -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

However, it doesn't work.

I have also tried to remove the page transition with no luck.

what i have found is that the flash only occurs on pages that are large and require you to scroll. I was wondering if anyone knows a solution for this annoying issue or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, this seems to be a common bug and there was nothing i could do to get rid of this annoying problem. I did find a work around. rather than using individual data-role="page", i placed all my content inside one page and using jquery to show and hide content, worked a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has now gone with the new versions fo software; Xcode 4.5, Cordova 2.1.0 and JQM 1.8.2. Transitions are smooth and overall performance has greatly increased!

Comment: Im still getting the issue on android with jquery mobile 1.2.0 + phonegap build